# How to pass Plus sign number to next page for Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

Problem: I want to pass the mobile phone No with a plus sign to next page. But only get mobile phone no without a plus sign.

help is much appreciated.

```
txtMobile1.text = "+61912345678"

 if (chk1.IsChecked.Value)
  {
 NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SendMsg.xaml?fn=" +  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(txtMobile1.Text) + "&Name=" + strName, UriKind.Relative));

  }


---- Receiving:

  if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("fn"))
  {
  strPassInMobileNo = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(this.NavigationContext.QueryString["fn"]) ;

   }

The received mobile phone no is : 61912345678  without the puls sign
```

Comment: What does the non-decoded result look like? this.NavigationContext.QueryString["fn"] ?

Comment: oh, if not using the solution provided by ChristiaanV below, it will pass the mobile phone whole thing ie: +61912345678, on the receiving end it show 61912345678 on the textBox. I did a check, there is a space char or some char but can not be seen in front of 61912345678.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(this.NavigationContext.QueryString["fn"]);`

Comment: On the sending part : Do I use httpUtility.HtmlEncode(txtMobile.text)? It does not work?

Comment: On the sending part you can use HttpUtility.UrlEncode(txtMobile.text), on the receiving part use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()

Comment: Thanks. It works. But why use different HttpUtiltiy Method? I guess I am pass querystring thus use URLEncode. Thanks

Comment: HttpUtility.UrlEncode is for encoding a full url, including domainname, querystring values etc. So because you're only encoding the querystring value, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode would work too.